# What is the type of the value of an <input> tag whose type is "number"?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have an input tag with the type attribute set to "number":

```
<input type="number" id="num-of-units"></input>
```

I want to get the current numeric value and compare it with some other numeric value:

```
if (document.getElementById("num-of-units").value > 0) ...
```

Can I safely assume that the 'value' is a numeric type and not a string type, or do I have to convert it?

P.S.: I realize I can probably test it on Firefox or something, but I want to be sure what the standard says.

Thanks

Comment: console.log(typeof value)

Comment: If you want to be sure whether this can be assumed or not, you don't need to know what the standard says but what the browsers do. The least I can tell that any browsers who don't support the "number" type yet will treat the input field as a type="text".

Comment: [it's a string](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/number)

Comment: I'm losing all my rep downvoting you, people, please read the question before answering !

Comment: @dystroy Why are you downvoting everyone? He asked for what the standard says about it. I linked to the same thing you did basically, but still received a down vote.

Comment: @dystroy: you will have to downvote 55887 times before: "*losing **all** my rep*" ;)

Comment: @crush because most answers doesn't answer at all... (and I didn't downvote everyone)

Comment: @dystroy My answer was the same thing you linked above in your comment, yet I get down-voted and you get 2 upvotes?

Comment: Great. 4 answers, some saying it's a string and some saying it's an integer, and some SO member down-voting everybody on this thread...

Comment: @barakmanos It's definitely a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to your question:

**Part 1**:

> Can I safely assume that the 'value' is a numeric type and not a
>   string type, or do I have to convert it?

Answer: No and Yes.

No, your cannot safely assume. Because it is actually a string. Value on `input`s are strings.

Also, because it will ignore non-numeric values and just return an empty string. So, you also have to check for an empty string in case there was a non-numeric entry.

Yes, you will have to convert it.

Check this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2k66J/10/**

**Part 2**:

> P.S.: I realize I can probably test it on Firefox or something, but I
>   want to be sure what the standard says

The standard was referred to by @dystroy in his comment. Anyway, here is what the standards say:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/number

scroll down to value where it says:

> value = string

Another source ref: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html

Comment: It's also plausible that someone could modify the value in memory, with the console, or some other means to give it a value other than a number, bypassing the `user interface` restrictions. Therefore, even if the `type=number` you should check that it is actually a number before treating it as such.

Comment: @crush: thanks for the update. i did a quick test based on what you said about changing the value through code. See this: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2k66J/11/** Even if the value is changed to a string through code or some other means, it will yield an **empty** string! But, yes I agree with you fully.

Comment: Unless the validation/sanitization occurs on retrieval of the `value` property, the value could still be modified with a memory editor to bypass validation. I'm not sure that's really anything to worry about in 99% of cases though.

Answer (score 5):

`.value` for any `<input>` field is a string.  The `type` attribute helps the browser control what is put into the input field or what type of input aides are used to accessorize the input element (e.g. a spinner control for numbers), but doesn't change the type of `.value`.

Demo Test: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2k66J/

If you want to see for yourself, run that demo in Firefox, IE, Chrome, etc... They all say it's a `string` type.  If you want the numeric value, you just convert it to a number yourself.

Comment: `HTMLInputElement` provides a single `value` property, which returns a string. The specification also mentions that `input` elements must be able to support an empty `string` as input. Therefore, it must always be a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

No. The value property of an input element type="number", will be retrieved in javascript as a string type value. You will have to convert it to a numeric data type (int, float) to use it as that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean "text" as a data type. I misspelled that. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: Just trying to help your answer be more accurate. No need for apologies!

Answer (score -2):

The standard says nothing about it. Have a look at [Ecma-262 revision 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

The short answer is you can't be sure.

Comment: Why -1? OP asked explicit if it's in the standard. It isn't.

Comment: The DOM has nothing to do with EcmaScript

Comment: JavaScript is based on EcmaScript. It's not EcmaScript.

Comment: @dystroy Exactly, therefore it isn't sure that one browser works like the other when it comes to DOM handling.

Comment: @schlingel Yet, you down-voted me for linking to the DOM standard.

Comment: @crush Nope, why would I? I only comment with "-1" and an explanation if I do so. You didn't answered on the topic but it wasn't wrong, so no point in downvoting you. By the way, Ecma Standard is still the core of JS which is the same on all browsers.

Comment: I did answer on the topic. I specifically mentioned where the DOM standard says `User agents should allow the user to set the value to an empty string.` which implies that the value of an `input` element has to be a `string`.

Comment: No. It was always there. I deleted the answer, though. Since I was receiving so many down-votes for what I perceived as a correct answer, I deferred, assuming that I must be ignorant on the subject. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything to suggest such.

Comment: @crush Don't know why someone would downvote. But OP never talked about HTML 5 and I seem to have skipped the quote. Makes sense, though.

Comment: Input `type=number` is HTML5.

Comment: Ah, than you're completely right but that doesn't have any consequences for the JS engines, or?

Answer (score -2):

It's always safer to double check your values;

1) Check that the value isn't "" or null;

2) if you're working with a server, even after validating your value, double check it on your Backend, specially if the value will be inserted to your database.

Technically, you're good to go, it will be html5-Validated as a number.

Hope this helped!

EDIT: Don't forget that your Var is in Javascript.